# Swift : Methods error in struct

Tags: swift, class, struct, func

I'm studying swift and I'm trying to understand the difference between classes and struct, which as I understand it, is in these two points:
1) Classes are reference types, Whereas structures are value types. That means That When you pass an instance of a structure to a function, return an instance from a function, or assign the value of a variable That Refers to a structure to another variable, the instance is copied. In other words, structures exhibit pass-by-value behavior. Swift strings, arrays, and dictionaries are all Implemented as structures.
By contrast, class instances are passed by reference-no copy is taken.
2) Classes can be subclassed to add behavior; structures can not.

why these two errors?
depends on the structure ?, because a class does not give me the same error.
[image: error message:]

Comment: These errors have nothing to do with your question.

Comment: As explained in the referenced thread, methods that modify properties of a struct must be marked as "mutating". You'll find that in the Swift book as well.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting those errors is that by default, the properties of a value type (i.e. a struct) cannot be modified from within its instance methods (e.g. your `newRad()` and `plusOne()` methods).